# Webview in a small window

Tags: android, user-interface

Is it possible to make the webview stay as a small window, instead of get the full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course... for example this will make a `WebView` appear next to a `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>    
  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
  />
  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/browser"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Taken from a [Mark Murphy example](http://github.com/commonsguy/). By the way, Mark Murphy is the <strike>common</strike>[guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) who answer this question some seconds ago.

Answer (score 1):

A `WebView` is a widget like any other. You control its size via the layout you put it in.